# html5 audio doesn't work in ios safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, safari

I have a game in which user clicks start button and after that by setInterval program randomly chooses an audio from an array and plays it. It works fine everywhere but safari.
I've also tried to use a ResponsiveVoice API. None of them works.
It looks as the code below:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'blabla';
```

and when user clicks start:

```
setInterval(function() {
  audio.play();
}, 2000);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your audio file isn't working AT ALL in safari, (not just with the setInterval js), then it's probably the file type that is the problem.

Currently, flac and ogg audio types are not supported in Safari, but are in other browsers. Likewise with Opus, another open-source file type.

MP3 and AAC are the most widely supported file types, followed by .wav 
The use of web audio is pretty widely supported also.

Refer to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com#search=audio) for more info.

Comment: First, audio format is MP3. Second, audio file works in safari but only when I invoke `play()` right after button click. It seems like problem is with `setInterval`

Comment: Thank you a lot for help, but, unfortunately, I just found out that it's impossible to play audio in safari in the way I want to. Touch or click event is mandatory to play an audio.

Comment: @LeonidGordun oh no... that's a bummer! oh well, we live and learn i suppose (and hopefully Safari will improve also!)